# iOS xcode constraints preview?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I am new to iPhone development (I am android developer) so all this interface builder way is really new to me.

I learned the best way to make interface responsive is to build it with constraints. I made few views and put constraints on them and it works as it should on the device, however there is this problem that constraints (as I read) are only applied on the build.

My question is: Can I see constraints in the interface builder (preview). All I see now are guidelines (orange) if something is misplaced. And If I want to move a view, could I just do this by changing the constraint and see the effect in the builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask IB to update your views' frames to match the constraints.  First, select your view controller or top-level view.  Then, go to the menu bar and choose Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Update Frames.  Or use the “Resolve Auto Layout Issues” pop-up in the lower-right corner of the IB pane:

[image: resolve auto layout issues popup]

If your layout doesn't turn out the way you want, you can undo (Edit > Undo Update Frames or <kbd>⌘Z</kbd>), modify your constraints, and try again.

Once your frames are in sync with your views, you can edit the constraints in the Size Inspector and IB should immediately update your views to match (if your edited constraints are satisfiable).